# Regular and finitely additive measure is $\sigma$-additive

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\tau)$ a topological space and $\mathcal{A}$ a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$. Let $\mu:\mathcal{A}\to [0,\infty]$ a finitely additive measure. We say that $\mu$ is a regular measure if for every $E \in \mathcal{A}$:

$$\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(G);G\,\,\text{open and}\,\,\,E\subset G,G \in \mathcal{A}\}=\sup\{\mu(K); K\,\,\,\text{compact and}\,\,\, K \subset E, K \in \mathcal{A}\}$$

How to show that every finitely addtive and regular measure $\mu:\mathcal{A}\to [0,\infty]$ is $\sigma$-additive?

**My attempt:**
Let $(A_n)$ an disjoint sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ and denote $A=\bigcup A_n.$

By the definition of $\inf$ and $\sup$ I constructed a sequence $(K_n)$ of compact sets and a sequence $(G_n)$ of open sets such that $K_i \subset A \subset G_k$ for all $i$ and $k$ natural numbers and such that
$$\mu(G_n)-\frac{1}{n}< \mu(A)<\mu(K_n)+\frac{1}{n} $$
Thus $\lim \mu(G_n)=\lim \mu(K_n)=\mu(A).$ We have the following property too:
$$\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_j \subset G_n.$$ And by the finite additivity of $\mu$ we see that $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mu(A_j) \leq \mu(G_n)$. It remains to show that $\mu(K_n) \leq \sum_{j=1}^{n} \mu(A_j)$ (or some inequality in that style, not necesseraly with these exacts indexes). But I don't know how to use the property that the all $K_n$ are compacts and all $G_n$ are open to prove this.

Any new strategy to solve the problem will be very well welcomed, but if someone see a way to continue my attempt to an solution, it will be even better.

Comment: The answer can be found in this post here [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3810842/560861).

Comment: Note that finite additivity implies countable superadditivity. Thus it suffices to show countable subadditivity.  Also note that finite additivity implies finite subadditivity. Given any union $E = \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty}E_j$, choose $K \subset E$ such that $\mu(E) - \varepsilon < \mu(K)$ and pick $U_j \supset E_j$ such that $\mu(U_j) \leq \mu(E_j) + 2^{-j}\varepsilon$. Then $$\mu(E) - \varepsilon < \mu(K) \leq \mu(\bigcup_{j = 1}^{N}U_j) \leq \sum_{j = 1}^{N}\mu(U_j) \leq \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}\mu(U_j) \leq \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}\mu(E_j) + \varepsilon.$$